# Click on markers mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have it so that clicking on the map creates a marker at that point. I am trying to add an event to the markers that will return the lnglat when the marker is clicked. The issue is I can't click the marker, the map just keeps creating new markers.

```js
map.on('click', function(e){
    let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map);
    marker.on('click', function(){
        console.log('hello');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markers are simple HTML elements, so you can add an event listener directly to them by calling `addEventListener` on their DOM node:

```
map.on('click', function(e){
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';
  el.style.height = '20px';
  el.style.width = '20px';
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

  el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // Prevent the `map.on('click')` from being triggered
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('hello');
  });

  let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map);
});
```

https://codepen.io/eddydg/pen/gZpbRj?editors=1010